# How to override strings.xml from build.gradle

Tags: android, xml

Need to replace  Values in strings.xml file based on productFlavors. I have two flavors both are using different url which is stored in strings.xml. How to do this stuf? Explain with code I am new to gralde.

```
productFlavors {
    staging {
        applicationId = "co.example.staging";
        //here i need a code to change values/override some values of strings.xml
    }
    production {
        applicationId = "co.example.breeze";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do that inside the gradle build file, just put the different strings into a directory called "values-flavourname/strings.xml", gradle will then take care of merging them correctly.

Comment: This approach requires we maintain two strings.xml file. That is something that gets updated a lot. Every time I update strings.xml I need to update the other one as well, or this soon becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I need  replace a particular string/strings  based on the flavor

Comment: You just need to put the string you want to change in the values-flavour/strings.xml file, not all of them. For the rest keep them in the standard values/strings.xml file. The merger will take care of creating the final file. Ah and don't forget to put the string ALSO in the standard values/strings.xml file so you have a default if no flavour is set or if its a flavour without a specific dir.

Comment: Tq for your reply. My question is , can we do it with in gradle or not?

Comment: Yes you can but it would be super complex and you would need to parse the XML, so why if you can just place the strings you want to be changed into values-flavourname/strings.xml ???

Comment: I did it by creating separate folder with in src for flavor staging and overridden the strings.xml file. And its working for me. I wanted to try another way to it. Which is best and efficient solution??

Comment: I don't really understand, why you do not like my proposal? Its the correct way and also the way suggested in Android Gradle manual.

Comment: I too would like to know if this is possible, as I want a string value to be configurable from command line parameter at build.